# Show content on mobile and hide on desktop

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have this code for implement a whats app button on a website, how i can show it only in mobile view and hide it on desktop view?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var options = {
            whatsapp: "+39 ", // WhatsApp number
            call_to_action: "contacts", // Call to action
            position: "right", // Position may be 'right' or 'left'
        };
        var proto = document.location.protocol, host = "whatshelp.io", url = proto + "//static." + host;
        var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; s.src = url + '/widget-send-button/js/init.js';
        s.onload = function () { WhWidgetSendButton.init(host, proto, options); };
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
    })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use only css with [`media-query`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)**

For example hide the button when the browser window is 600px wide or less:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    button{
        display: none;
    }
}
```